# How to make a file variable buffer local?

Tags: file-local-variables, sh-mode

I have customized the variable sh-indentation with 4, but in one file I would like to use a different value. So I defined a file variable:

```
# -*- mode: sh; sh-indentation: 2; -*-
```

But the result is not what I have expected. When I open the file the values are:

```
sh-indentation is a variable defined in `sh-script.el'.
Its value is 2
Original value was 4
Local in buffer .szi; global value is 4
```

The file variable seems to set the global value but not the buffer local value.

How can I set the buffer local value with the file variable?

Comment: It says the global value is still 4 so I think it didn't override it.

Comment: @hatschipuh But sh-mode uses 4 and not 2, if I do a indent-region. Is it a bug in sh-mode, that it ignores the local value?

Comment: I tested it shortly on my side and it seems to accept the local value on my side.

Comment: Your `describe-variable` result looks fine.. it says "Its value is 2". May be you should provide a full recipe on how one can recreate this issue from an `emacs -Q` session. Can you see the problem in an `emacs -Q` session? What is your emacs version?

Comment: Also what do you get when you do `C-h v indent-region-function`?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, *all* file-local and directory-local variables are (necessarily) buffer-local.

Here, Emacs is telling you that `sh-indentation` is buffer-local (with a value of `2`) in that buffer.

You can trust that Emacs isn't lying to you, and that it's not ignoring the local value.

This should suggest to you that maybe the behaviour you're looking for is *not* entirely dependent on the variable you've set.

The most important variable you've missed is `sh-basic-offset`, but there's a whole section on indentation in the Commentary of `sh-script.el` which you should read:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `sh-script` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: @ceving If this answer helps, please update the question title and explanation so that it is useful to other users.